# Си в Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c, visual-c++

Осталась ли в новой версии поддержка чистого C? Или для изучения на C и разбирания примеров на этом языке лучше использовать другую IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Должна быть. В 2010 студии открываешь свойства cpp файла, там "С/С++" -> "Дополнительно" -> "Компилировать как"  выбираешь "Компилировать как код C". В 2012 должно быть примерно так же. Поддержка C не такая вещь, которую можно выкинуть. :)
А студия, на мой взгляд, лучшая среда в которой можно учиться программированию.

Comment: mikelsv,поддерживаю,есть конечно другие ide)